# Is it allowed to remove items from a ConcurrentDictionary while iterating it in a Foreach loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I'm building an app in C# using Visual Studio. I'm using a `ConcurrentDictionary`. I'm iterating through all the elements in that `ConcurrentDictionary`, and perform an action on each element. If the action fails, I remove the element from the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

I know that this is bad behavior if you do that with normal Dictionaries, Lists, etc... But is it allowed with a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

So my question is: Is the below code fragment correct? More specifically, am I allowed to use `TryRemove` on the `ConcurrentDictionary` that I'm iterating?

```
foreach (var prop in _PropertyByPropId)
{
    // Add the Property to the Pool. If successfully parsed, we will get a SimId not equal to -1.
    int iSimId = PropertyPool.AddPropertyInPool(PNPDeviceID, prop.Value, PortName);
    if (iSimId != -1)
    {
        // If successful, also add it to the dictionary by iSimId
        if (!_PropertyBySimId.TryAdd(iSimId, prop.Value))
            // In the (very unlikely) case that a Property is added twice (same iSimId), we remove the second Property
            _PropertyByPropId.TryRemove(prop.Key, out _);
    }
    else
        // If unsuccessful, remove the Property
        _PropertyByPropId.TryRemove(prop.Key, out _);
}
```

I found an older thread [removing-items-from-a-concurrentdictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750142/removing-items-from-a-concurrentdictionary) on this forum, but that seems to give answers related to the multithreading aspects of a `ConcurrentDictionary`. I think my question is different?

Comment: It is definitely thread safe, read remarks in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getenumerator It should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to remove items from a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` during an enumeration. All operations on this collections are thread-safe and atomic. Nevertheless, performing two atomic operations in succession does not equal to performing one combined atomic operation. It is entirely possible that the data in the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` might become semantically corrupted, because two concurrent combined operations interfered with each other in an unexpected way. I am not in a position to judge if your specific scenario and usage, allows semantic data corruption to occur.

The `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` collection is excellent for simple multithreading scenarios, but becomes exponentially unsuitable, a headache and a bug factory, when the scenarios become more complicated. At some point of complexity it becomes more  safe and productive to go with a standard `Dictionary<K,V>` protected with the `lock` statement, instead of trying to tame the concurrent beast.

Comment: Here's the doc link: "The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getenumerator?view=net-7.0

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I understand that it is safe with concurrent reads and writes. But I didn't realize that this also means that you can delete items within a foreach loop. If an external thread can change the content of the ConcurrentDictionary (means also deleting items) while I'm in a foreach loop, then it indeed means that I can change the contents any time in my own foreach loop. Took me some days to realize this....